# Помогите преобразовать массив в объект массивов с ключом каждого из них

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив:

```
["Августина Екатерина", "Августовский Борис", "Богатова Августина"]
```

, мне нужно его отсортировать в объект такого вида:

```
{
  А: ["Августина Екатерина", "Августовский Борис"],
  Б: ["Богатова Августина"]
}
```

Массив динамический, формируется после запроса, суть - сгруппировать по первой букве фамилии чтобы потом списком поиск отображать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = ["Августина Екатерина", "Августовский Борис", "Богатова Августина"];

const output = input.reduce((rslt, val) => {
  const key = val.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase(),                           // [0] и charAt(0) менее надежны чем slice, но можно и их использовать
        arr = Array.isArray(rslt[key]) ? rslt[key] : (rslt[key] = []); // получаем ссылку на значение целевого свойства (на массив) в объекте, создав такое свойство при необходимости
  arr.push(val);
  return rslt;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: спасибо. именно то, что я и хотел.

Comment: я хочу сделать вот так:{card.map((item) => {return <div className="author-cell"><h4 className="author-title">{item[0]}</h4>
                                {item.map((el) => <p className="author-content">{el}</p>)}</div>})}, метод который вы предложили хорош, но не подошёл под то, как я думаю. можно его как-то модифицировать под мой способ? или мне можно воспользоваться им по другому?

Comment: @АндрейАзовкин, вообще непонятно при чем тут `map` - результатом решения задачи является **объект** с массивами в свойствах, а не простой массив. Метод `map` у объектов конечно же отсутствует.

Comment: сделал так:
 const render = (obj) => {
        for ( var propName in obj) 
        {return <div className="author-cell"><h4 className="author-title">{propName}</h4>
        {obj[propName].map((el) => <p className="author-content">{el}</p>)}</div>}
        }
но почему то берётся только первый элемент из объекта, хотя в документации написано что for..in перебирает все ключи объекта и их величины...

Comment: @АндрейАзовкин, так ты же сам написал оператор`return`, вот он и выполняется (на первой же итерации цикла происходит выход из функции). И тут лучше применять статический метод `Object.keys`, либо `Object.entries` - использовать `for..in` с объектами таким образом крайне нежелательно, т.к. подобный цикл перебирает и прототипные свойства объекта тоже (а не только собственные).

Comment: @АндрейАзовкин, [вот такое](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/hweeTyqh) пытаешься изобразить, или не?

Comment: да. уже получилось, ты очень помог, большое спасибо! просто добавил элемент еще один и нарисовалось всё ОК!)

Comment: @АндрейАзовкин, пожалуйста! Раз ответ помог - нажми "галочку" слева от него (под кнопками-стрелками).